# iZotope RX2: limiting the noise profile bandwidth

Tags: noise-reduction, izotope, denoiser

is there a way to limit the bandwidth of the noise profile? I mean, let's say I only want to denoise the highs from a recording and keep the rest. By now I can't find a way, since the noise profile is full range.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,
Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy and paste into a new clip the sound you want RX2 to learn, then use a standard EQ to bandpass it down to only the frequencies you want affected, you can then use the band passed version for RX2 to "learn" and therefore only affect the specified frequencies in the main recording.

Comment: Simple, effective idea!  I'll have to remember this one.

Answer (score 3):

What is your use case scenario? Field recordings or vocals? 
You can if you have the advanced version of 2 or 3. You could also use the 'envelope' function to create a frequency curve that allows you to attenuate noise in a specific frequency range. Highly useful function especially with complex material (with loud low or midrange sounds), because it makes 'filtering' easier for RX somehow. (Less pumping artifacts).

Comment: Thank you, Arnoud. My scenario is field recording. I tried to isolate thunders under an heavy rain. The result is good, but a bit muddy. I'll try with Ian's advice and save for RX Advanced ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about RX2 but you can in RX3.  It's possible in the standalone module to select your frequencies as well as drag points around on the noise print.